# UIView.transition fades in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My call looks something like this:

```
UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.5,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                  animations: { button.hidden = false },
                  completion: null)
```

When I use it to show a button, it works as expected with a nice fade-in. When I use it to hide (with `button.hidden = true`), it again works fine in the iOS simulator, but on a device - iPhone or iPad - it just disappears with no fade.

The only significant difference I can find is that my devices are running iOS 10.2, but the simulator only has 10.1. Xcode isn't giving me the option to download a 10.2 simulator.

Is there anything else I could be missing? Are there other animation options I should use?

It may be worth noting that the button I'm hiding and showing is inside a `UIBarButtonItem` in a navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my button is in the navigation bar, I ended up using `navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(buttons, animated: true)`. With that, the animation worked fading in an out on both simulators and devices.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but just with a standard UIView within a UIView. I fixed mine by passing the superview of the view I was hiding as the `with:` parameter. I think re-reading the docs this is how you're supposed to do it, and the fact that it worked by passing the view in question may have just been a convenient bug that Apple might have fixed in 10.2, but that's just speculation.

Anyway, re-writing the OP's code using what I did to fix mine to illustrate:

```
UIView.transition(with: button.superview!, duration: 0.5,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                  animations: { button.hidden = false },
                  completion: null)
```